# SQL Server Cannot Create Transactional replication Error 14013

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am trying to create transactional replication but encountered the following error:

Please help,

[[image: SQL Server Replication Error 14013[1]]

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators. Please, when asking questions related to error messages, avoid pasting the image of the error message. Paste the error message text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps before setting up a Publication.

[Tutorial: Prepare SQL Server for replication (publisher, distributor, subscriber)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

- Create Windows accounts for replication.
- Prepare the snapshot folder.
- **Configure distribution.**

I believe you skipped this. If not, please edit you question with the steps you already followed successfully.